# RxJava 2 Zip operation in different threads

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have created a really simple example using RxJava 2 (everything I have developed was using RxJava 1) and I have found next behavior that I don't understand at all. I have next Observable with zip operation:

```
Observable.zip(getGame(gameId), getDetail(gameId), getReviews(gameId),
            (game, detail, reviews) -> new GameInfo(game, detail, reviews))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(sendGameInfo(asyncResponse));
```

Each of the methods returns an instance of Observable. In theory, I would expect that each of the method (getGame, getDetail, ...) would be executed in parallel in a new Thread, but doing a sysout I noticed that all the time is the same Thread so they are not executed in parallel. I suppose that this is the expected behavior but if I would like to make in parallel is there a way to do it without having to define a runnable inside each of the observable?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to subscribeOn every Observable

```
 Observable.zip(getGame(gameId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)),
            getDetail(gameId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)),
            getReviews(gameId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)),
            (game, detail, reviews) -> new GameInfo(game, detail, reviews))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
        .subscribe(sendGameInfo(asyncResponse));
```

Comment: You don't have to create 4 custom schedulers for this, just factor out `Schedulers.from(executor)` and use the variable 4 times.